# Do I need a dedicated IP address to install an SSL certificate on Azure Windows VM with a FQDN?

Tags: iis, azure, ssl-certificate, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016

I have an Azure Windows VM. I want to manually install the SSL certificate rather than use Azure's Keyvault.

The server has a public IP address, but it is non-static. It also has a FQDN (not sure if that's relevant). I also registered a domain name, so I'm not trying to tie the certificate directly to the FQDN.

I'm going to purchase a certificate from Namecheap, but their documentation suggests that "A dedicated IP address is required to install an SSL certificate.".

Am I going to run into issues with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dedicated, I think, in this context means not shared with anyone else. Azure assigns dedicated addresses, so you will not run into issues as long as your DNS records are properly set. Azure always assigns internal DNS name which ends with Azure-owned domain (for example, `example.azurewebsites.net`) and its binding to IP is managed automatically by Azure itself.

If you use custom domain, then in your DNS zone you create a CNAME entry which points to an Azure's internal name. In this case, when client resolves `myresource.example.com`, it receives a CNAME alias pointed to `example.azurewebsites.net` and which is eventually resolved to an IP address assigned to that resource at particular point. This means that Azure can swap IP addresses on your resource and you will always reach that particular IP address, because name-address bindings are managed by Azure automatically.